# .wmv player not working

Tags: silverlight-2.0, media-player, wmv

So...I've got an embedded object that looks like this:

```
         <div id="vid">
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var cnt = document.getElementById("vid");
            var src = 'wmvplayer.xaml';
            var cfg = {
                file:'images/photostory.wmv',
                height:'240',
                width:'360',
                windowless:'true'
                };
            var ply = new jeroenwijering.Player(cnt,src,cfg);
            so1.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
            so1.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
            so1.addVariable('file','images/photostory.wmv');
            so1.write('vid');
            </script>
        </div>
```

..with all the right scripts in the head and everything.  The player loads just fine, all the functionality is there, but the video just wont play.  It seems like it starts to, but nah...

Thanks, in advance, for any help.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need this bit:

```
        so1.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
        so1.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
        so1.addVariable('file','images/photostory.wmv');
        so1.write('vid');
```

That's just for the FLV Player embedded with SWFObject.

Beyond that, my guess is that you might be referencing the file incorrectly. I'd try using a tool like Firebug or Charles Proxy to make sure that your browser is requesting the file correctly.

Best,

Zach

Developer, LongTail Video

Comment: Thanks Zach, and btw nice product!  Still not showing up though.  Must be a referencing issue, that makes the most sense to me, but I just don't see where I'm making the error...